# quadratic equation with complex coeeficient

Tags: quadratics

Given that p and q are real and that $1+2i$ is a root of the equation :

> $$Z^2+(p+5i)z+q(2-i)=0$$

Determine
The value of p and q.
The other root of the equation.

Comment: I see $(2-1)$ but all the answer-ers write $2-i$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^2+(p+5i)z+q(2-i)=0$

$z=1+2i$ is a root therefore

$(1+2i)^2+(p+5i)(1+2i)+q(2-i)=0$

$1+4i-4+p+2pi+5i-10+2q-qi=0$

$(p+2q-13)+i(2p-q+9)=0$

we have the system

$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 p+2q-13&=0 \\ 
 2p-q+9&=0 
\end{matrix}\right.
$

multiply the second equation by $2$ and add

$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 p+2q-13&=0 \\ 
 4p-2q+18&=0 
\end{matrix}\right.
$

$5p=-5\to p=-1$

$-1+2q-13=0\to q=7$

The other root is $z_2=-7i$

$z^2+(-1+5i)z+14-7i=0$

$$z=\frac{1-5i\pm\sqrt{(-1+5i)^2-4(14-7i)}}{2}=\frac{1-5i\pm\sqrt{1-10i-25-56+28i}}{2}=\\=\frac{1-5i\pm\sqrt{-80+18i}}{2}=\frac{1-5i\pm\sqrt{(1+9i)^2}}{2}=\frac{1-5i\pm(1+9i)}{2}$$
$z_1=\dfrac{1-5i-1-9i}{2}=-7i$

$z_2=\dfrac{1-5i+1+9i}{2}=1+2i$

Hope this helps

Comment: please find the othere root of the equation by subtituting the value of p and q

Comment: @AdebGHAYOUR I've done my best. Hope it is useful...

Comment: how you subtitute -80 with 1

Comment: $-80+18i=1+18i+81i^2=(1+9i)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha = 1+2i$

Let $\beta = a+bi$ be the other root

Then $\alpha+\beta = -(p+5i)$

and $\alpha\times\beta = q(2-i)$

Now figure out p and q with two equations.

$(1+2i+a+bi) = -p -5i$

$a+1 +(2+b) = -p-5i$

$(1+2i)(a+bi) = q(2-i)$

$a+1 =-p$

$b+2=-5$

$b = -7$

$a-2b = 2q$

$2a+b = -q$

$4a+2b = -2q$

Adding the last two, we get

$a = 0$ and $q = -b = 7$

$p = -1$

$\beta = -7i$

Comment: **2** equations. **3** unknowns.

Comment: I think third equation can be found by simply substituting the root in equation.

Comment: i couldn't understand can you explain it more simpler write down all the steps

Comment: It's wrong and let me ask the reason why you took a longer way :)

Comment: can you please write down the steps how you get q and then p

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   z^2+(p+5i)z+q(2-i)
   &= (z-a-bi)(z-1-2i) \\
   &= z^2 -[(a+1)+(b+2)i]z+[(a-2b)+(2a+b)i] \\
\hline
    p &= -a-1 \\
    5 &= -b-2 \\
   2q &= a-2b \\
   -q &= 2a+b \\
\hline
    p &= -a-1 \\
    \color{red}b &\color{red}= \color{red}{-7} \\
   2q &= a+14 \\
   \color{red}{-2q} &\color{red}= \color{red}{4a-14} \\
\hline
    \color{red}p &\color{red}= \color{red}{-1} \\
    \color{red}b &\color{red}= \color{red}{-7} \\
   \color{red}a &\color{red}= \color{red}0 \\
   \color{red}{q} &\color{red}= \color{red}7 \\
\hline
\end{align}

So $p=-1$, $q=7$, and the other root is $-7i$.

### check

\begin{align}
   (z-0+7i)(z-1-2i)
   &= z^2+(-1+5i)z + (14-7i) \\
   &= z^2+(p+5i)z+q(2-i)
\end{align}